# Convert pandas dataframe into dictionary with custom keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation where I need to print the frequencies of data appearing in one of the columns of my dataframe.

Suppose my column is `status`, then performing

```
df['status'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

outputs

```
 {
    "Deleted": 56,
    "New": 25,
    "Draft": 24,
    "Assigned": 11,
    "Job Complete": 10,
    "Active": 8,
    "Requested": 3,
    "Cancelled": 3,
    "Footage Provided": 1
 }
```

I want to format the output as:

```
 {
    {status: "Deleted", value: 56},
    {status: "New", value: 25},
    {status: "Draft", value: 24},
    ...
  }
```

I'm new to pandas. Please help.

Comment: So you want a nested dictionary? What are the keys for the high level dictionary?

Comment: Also, there are typos in your desired output format.

Comment: @b-fg ok fixed the output format now.

Comment: Please also clarify my first question, thanks.

Comment: @b-fg is it a nested dictionary?  I just need a list of objects of type {status:"xyz", value: 10}

Comment: It is if you use `{ }`. Change that for `[ ]` if you want a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below list comprehension:

```
print([{'status': k, 'value': v} for k, v in df['status'].value_counts().to_dict().items()])
```

Output's gonna be expected.

Comment: Totally forgot about list comprehensions as I was hoping to solve it somehow from pandas itself. Thanks this is exactly what I needed. 

A small typo here though, curly brace in the end should be replaced with square bracket.
```
`[{'status': k, 'value': v} for k, v in booking_client_freq_dict.items()]`
```

Comment: @saran3h Haha, happy to help, :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just reformat the `pandas` output dictionary to your desired list format. Iterate over the dictionary and append the keys and values as a dictionary object to you list:

```
d1 = df['status'].value_counts().to_dict()
l = []
for k, v  in d1.items():
    l.append({'status': k, 'value': v})
print(l)
```

Output

```
[{'status': 'Deleted', 'value': 56}, 
 {'status': 'New', 'value': 25}, 
 {'status': 'Draft', 'value': 24},
 ...
]
```

Comment: That's my original output itself. I need every object in the format: `{status:"xyz", value: 10}`. found the solution anyway. Thanks.

Comment: How is that different from my answer?